# What Dpi should I selecte for scale 1.75?

Tags: android, dpi

I have a device which has scale equal 1.75. Now I want to choose value resource for it and don't know which dpi I should select `hdpi or xhdpi`.

My device is sony xperia j:

screen size  = 480*854, scale = 1.75, inch = 4.0

Comment: post your device full specs

Answer (score 1):

You can check the wiki for full specification of device with there corresponding DPI

In your device it is **hdpi** based from this [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_displays_by_pixel_density#Motorola_Mobility)

```
10 (4.0)    480x854 96 (245)        hdpi
```